# Mulitiple equilibria in zero sum games

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

How could we prove that for all two-player zero-sum games: if ,  and ,  are Nash equilibria, then so are ,  and , ;

Can we also proof all Nash equilibria have the same utility?

Comment: This follows from the minmax characterization of Nash equillibria of zero-sum games.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/53552/25335, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4579838/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).